# VSFTPD - FTP over TLS - Upload stops after exactly 82k?

Tags: centos, ftp, tls, vsftpd

I installed a VSFTP daemon on a CentOS server, using a RSA certificate for logging in using explicit TLS. Now, I cannot upload more than 82k.

With files under that limit, there is no problem. The FTP works like a charm. But as soon as a file reaches 82k with FileZilla (81,952 bytes to be exact), the transfer will stop, and the FTP client hangs until time out is reached.

FTP client console:

```
15:10:21    Command:    STOR jquery-1.7.2.min.js  
15:10:21    Response:   150 Ok to send data.  
15:11:21    Error:  Connection timed out  
15:11:21    Error:  File transfer failed after transferring 82 KB in 60 seconds
```

/var/log/vsftpd.log

```
FTP command:  Client "x.x.x.x", "STOR jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
FTP response: Client "x.x.x.x", "150 Ok to send data."
OK UPLOAD:    Client "x.x.x.x", "jquery-1.7.2.min.js", 81952 bytes, 1.32Kbyte/sec
FTP response: Client "x.x.x.x", "226 File receive OK." // NOT okay, file is bigger
// No mention of error here
```

I cannot find relevant info about this problem, apart from a possible problem with `trans_chunk_size` (not mentioned in default config), but I tried different sizes and it has no impact on the problem.
`trans_chunk_size=4096`
`trans_chunk_size=8192`
`trans_chunk_size=9999`

Ofcourse, after every configuration change, I restarted the server:
`/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart`

What else can cause this?

It's not the latest version, but it's the latest update within the repositories that has been deemed fit for enterprise usage:

Package info:

```
$ yum info vsftpd  
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror  
Installed Packages  
Name       : vsftpd  
Arch       : x86_64  
Version    : 2.0.5  
Release    : 24.el5_8.1  
Size       : 286 k  
Repo       : installed  
Summary    : vsftpd - Very Secure Ftp Daemon  
URL        : http://vsftpd.beasts.org/  
License    : GPL  
Description: vsftpd is a Very Secure FTP daemon. It was written completely from scratch.
```

Comment: Got pcaps showing whether the problem's at the network layer or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is at the client side. Have you tried another client program: [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/), [`TLSWrap`](http://freecode.com/projects/tlswrap), ...?

- http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/7837
- https://savannah.gnu.org/support/?107660

Comment: Thanks. Before I set this up, I was running the same daemon without TLS and it worked fine. I would have to set up a different FTP server also with RSA/TLS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use FTP on my server anymore, too much hassle.

But if I remember correctly, the problem was indeed (partially) client-side and a workaround was to compile the latest version of FileZilla. Not the (forever outdated) version in the Ubuntu repositories.

This is what the guys at FileZilla pointed out themselves, but I cannot find the resource back at this moment.